# MySQL - Finding time difference between rows for different Id's

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which consists of below data:

```
ID   status-before             status-current         DATE-timestamp         
5    Un-Assigned                Assigned              2013-12-17 14:14:04
5    Assigned                   Completed             2013-12-21 14:14:04
7    Un-Assigned                Assigned              2014-01-02 14:14:04 
7    Assigned                   Completed             2014-01-21 14:14:04
7    Completed                  Locked                2014-01-21 14:14:04
8    Un-Assigned                Assigned              2014-12-21 14:14:04
8    Assigned                   Completed             2014-12-27 14:14:04
```

I have used group by to group ids and sorted timestamp field. I dont know how to use rownum(or any other method) to calculate time difference of rows of only the ones with same id.

I want my final output to be as below

```
ID   status-before              status-current     DATE-timestamp       Time Diff(Hours)
5    Un-Assigned                Assigned        2013-12-17 14:14:04    xx
5    Assigned                   Completed       2013-12-21 14:14:04    xx
7    Un-Assigned                Assigned        2014-01-02 14:14:04    xx 
7    Assigned                   Completed       2014-01-21 14:14:04    xx
7    Completed                  Locked          2014-01-21 14:14:04    xx
8    Un_Assigned                Assigned        2014-12-21 14:14:04    xx
8    Assigned                   Completed       2014-12-27 14:14:04    xx
```

Comment: Why two status_after, and final output is not meaningful.

Comment: Can you manually write what 'xx' should be for the three rows with ID = 7?

Comment: Without knowing what `xx` should be, your question is unclear.  If there are only two rows per `id`, why not just have a result set with one row per `id`?

Comment: Why does your table having same column **status-after** name ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `TIMEDIFF` to return `hours:minutes:seconds` or `DATEDIFF` to return `days`

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('complete.TIMESTAMP','assign.TIMESTAMP');
SELECT DATEDIFF('complete.TIMESTAMP','assign.TIMESTAMP');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the time difference between Assigned and Completed you can use the script below.

```
SELECT a.ID, 
   b.[status-after], 
   a.[DATE-timestamp], 
   DATEDIFF(Hour, a.[DATE-timestamp], b.[DATE-timestamp]) AS TimeDiff_Hours
FROM YourTable a
JOIN YourTable b 
ON a.ID = b.ID AND b.[status-after] = 'Completed'
WHERE a.[status-after] = 'Assigned'
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want the time diff to the *next* status for the id.  Let me assume MySQL prior to version 8.  You can get the next time stamp using a correlated subquery and then use `timestampdiff()`:

```
select t.*,
       timestampdiff(hour, date_timestamp, next_datetimestamp) as diff_hours
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.date_timestamp
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id and
                    t2.date_timestamp > t.date_timestamp
              order by t2.date_timestamp asc
             ) as next_date_timestamp
      from t
     ) t;
```

If you are using MySQL 8.0, you can simplify this logic using the `lead()` function.